# Mentioning actors by their roles

Tags: phrase-request

I want to say:

> Actor as/of **Dr. Smuggler** role, **Mr Even** role Dies at the age of 80.

Is that Correct?

An actor played several memorable roles and I want to mention him from the perspective of his roles.

Can I keep this form ==> **Actor of ..... role**

Comment: Name, actor who played Dr. Smuggler and Mr. Even, dies at 80.

Answer (score 2):

You might use

> John Doe of *the* Dr Smuggler and Mr Even roles, died at age 60.

if the named roles are very famous otherwise you risk assuming everyone knows what you are talking about.  More usually is used

> John Doe who played Dr Smuggler in the *Smuggler series* and Mr Even in the *Even series* died at age 60.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to phrase this.  Some examples from today's headlines:

> John Hurt, Alien and Harry Potter actor, dies aged 77
>
> Actor John Hurt of 'Elephant Man,' 'Midnight Express' and 'Alien' dies at 77
>
> Actor John Hurt, star of 'The Elephant Man', dies aged 77
>
> John Hurt, British Actor Hailed for His Shape-Shifting Roles, Dies at 77